# Mount samba share as if it was a local drive or folder in Windows

Tags: windows, network-shares, samba, traktor

I have a fileserver running FreeNAS (FreeBSD), serving a Samba share with my music on it.
I also have a Windows 10 computer with [Traktor DJ 2](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/traktor/dj-software/traktor-dj-2/) installed.

Traktor DJ 2 fails to read anything from the network share, silently. I have read, while trying to get it to work, that it also writes a bunch of changes to any files it uses, which I also don't want.

I figure the easiest way to get it to work would be to mount the Samba share as read only, in a way that appears to programs on the computer to be just a local drive or folder, so whatever stupid stuff is happening to cause Traktor DJ 2 to fail to read from the network share is abstracted away behind whatever solution presents it as something local instead.

I've already tried:

- using the "map network drive" feature in Windows. That exhibits the same problems as trying to use the network share directly.
- `mklink /D "C:\Music" "\\192.168.1.2\RO Music"` (where `RO Music` is a read-only share of `music/`) also exhibited the same problems. I notice that doing that also had a different icon in explorer - a folder with a shortcut arrow, as compared to just a folder for the local folders also in `C:\`.

In short I want something completely subversive so this stupid program works properly. Copying my music collection to a local folder is not an option, as my Windows computer has less hard drive space total than my music collection.

Comment: I've read that people setting their local music collections to read only caused no issues, as the program _also_ writes that data to its own local cache, and it's for "convenience" that it also writes it to the actual files.  Regardless, it doesn't work on the write-accessible share either, so that's nothing to do with it, but sincerely thank you for your attempt to help.

Comment: Did you try making a junction with [`mklink /J` to the symbolic link you created with `mklink /D`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491362/1256347)?

Comment: And is it possible to configure [WebDAV on the FreeNAS](https://archive.freenas.org/9.3/STABLE/201412200530/doc/freenas_sharing.html#webdav-shares) and map that as a network drive or use it with a [WebDAV client](https://www.google.com/searchq=webdav+client+windows)?